# How do I convert an SDDP.State object into a number or tuple in SDDP.jl?

Tags: julia, stochastic-dual-dynamic-programming, sddp

I want to collect evaluation data and for it I need to collect data in numbers not SDDP.state objects, so how can I do that in [SDDP.jl](https://github.com/odow/SDDP.jl).

Comment: Also, since you've had quite a few SDDP.jl-related questions recently, I might gently suggest that you post on the JuMP forum: https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/opt/13, or open an issue at SDDP.jl in future: https://github.com/odow/SDDP.jl/issues/new. This is a pretty niche topic for StackExchange and it's not somewhere that most people will look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x::SDDP.State` objects have a `.in` field and a `.out` field, corresponding to the value of the incoming and outgoing state variables at a node. Pick which one makes sense to use for your application.